# How to change Windows' DNS settings using only built-in modules?

Tags: python, windows, dns

I want to write a python program that compares the DNS server speed of a list of DNS server IPs and then changes the windows setting for the particular wifi connection accordingly. Where can I learn how to access DNS settings? I don't want solution, just point me in the right direction.

PS: I don't want to use any extra modules like `dnspython`, just the default modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following on the command line to change your DNS server:

```
C:\> netsh interface ip set dns Ethernet0 static 8.8.8.8
```

You should replace `Ethernet0` and `8.8.8.8` with relevant values.

To do this in Python, just use the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(
    ["netsh", "interface", "ip", "set", "dns", "Ethernet0", "static", "8.8.8.8"])
```

Comment: What is Ethernet0 ? I assume 8.8.8.8 is Ip. BUt in windows there is requirement of two IPs. Like that of OpenDNs. How do I enter two IPs?

Comment: `Ethernet0` is the name of the network adapter you see when you type `ifconfig`. To add a second DNS server (for example, `4.4.4.4`) use `netsh interface ip add dns Ethernet0 4.4.4.4 index=2`